# How to add border to SearchBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a search bar like this

[image: SearchBar]

I have tried this

```
SearchBar(
    leadingIcon = {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.image_des)
        )
    },
    trailingIcon = {
        if (isActive) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.image_des),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        isActive = false
                    }
            )
        } else {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(0.8.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.4f)
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                )
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.LocationOn,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.image_des)
                )
                Text(text = location)
            }
        }
    },
    placeholder = {
        Text(text = placeHolder)
    },
    colors = SearchBarDefaults.colors(
        containerColor = Color.White
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(10.dp)
        .border(0.5.dp, Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))
) {
}
```

But my border doesn't match with the SearchBar's container

I wonder if there is any way to achieve my requirement

I look forward to any advice or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you try making custom search bar?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just want to make my code simpler with the SearchBar component. If it is impossible to meet my requirements with the SearchBar, then I will try to create my own custom search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little bit of modification from the Material3 SearchBar. I hope this helps if anybody has a problem like me.

```
    fun CustomSearchBar(
    query: String,
    onQueryChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearch: (String) -> Unit,
    active: Boolean,
    onActiveChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    placeHolder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (()->Unit)? = null,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = query,
            onValueChange = onQueryChange,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                color = Color.Black
            ),
            enabled = enabled,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = { onSearch(query) }),
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(56.dp)
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .onFocusChanged { onActiveChange(it.isFocused) }
                .semantics {
                    onClick {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                        true
                    }
                },
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .border(
                            width = 1.dp,
                            color = Color.LightGray,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 30.dp)
                        )
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 12.dp) // inner padding

                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Row(
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
                        ) {
                            leadingIcon?.let { it() }
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Box {
                                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                                    placeHolder?.let { it() }
                                }
                                innerTextField()
                            }
                        }
                        Box(
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                        ) {
                            trailingIcon?.let { it() }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        LaunchedEffect(active) {
            if (!active) {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        }
    }
}
```